# How delete all pushable commits?

Tags: git

I try to use the `git filter-branch` to remove some big files. This was not a good idea because it rewrite the history and create a new branch doubling all commits.

Now I want to redo this. I see in SmartGit (a git graphic interface) that it create a lot of pushable commits. How can I delete it and undo all this commits?

I will have to delete one by one using the SHA ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't yet push them you can do a `git reset --hard HEAD~X` where X is the number of commits.

Comment: Wow, great idea. I checkout in the new branch and was deleting all commits until the time it start to double.

Comment: You could also do `git reset --hard remoteName/branchName`.  That will reset your branch back to where the remote one is, without having to count how far back to go.

Comment: OK, but this is more security, I can see what I am doing :)

Answer (score 0):

`git filter-branch` will create a backup copy of your unwritten refs inside the `.git/refs/original/` directory.
You might get lucky by moving those refs to their previous location (`.git/refs/heads/`) – be sure to make a backup copy of your complte repository first ;)

That way you don't have to reset each branch head separately.